# i have an error in my sql syntax by Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

this is my query

```
CREATE TABLE buku(
    kd_buku VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    judul_buku VARCHAR(60),
    kd_karang VARCHAR(5),
    kd_terbit VARCHAR(5),
    jumlah INT
);

INSERT INTO buku VALUES
('21','kalkulus','10','1',10),
('22','Metode Numerik','11','2',20),
('23','Sistem basis data','12','3',40),
('24','Pengantar Teknologi Informasi','12','3',41);

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ubahbuku
(IN kd_buku VARCHAR(5), IN judul_buku VARCHAR(60), IN kd_karang VARCHAR(5), IN kd_terbit VARCHAR(5), jumlah INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE buku SET kd_buku=@kd_buku, judul_buku=@judul_buku, kd_karang=@kd_karang, kd_terbit=@kd_terbit, jumlah=@jumlah;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL ubahbuku('24','sosiologi','10','1',30);
```

I have a problem when calling the ubahbuku function
**Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'**
can you help me?

Comment: There is no where clause in the update so you are attempting to update every row to 24 as the primary key..

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Of what? Which row did you want to update?

Comment: yes how to using ubahbuku function

Comment: You answer the second part of my comment..What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your choice of primary key may prove problematic in due course. What's wrong with an autoincrementing id?

Comment: Not only are you trying to update every row with the same primary key value, you are trying to update using a primary key value (24) that already exists before the update. So you need *both* a `WHERE` clause *and* a non-duplicate primary key. Unless your intention is to update the row whose PK is already 24, which isn't stated: in which case it would be customary to omit the PK column from the update.

Answer (score 1):

As has been already pointed out in the comments, your proc's update has no `WHERE` clause, so it will try to update every record in the table with the same incoming primary key value.  Instead, add a `WHERE` clause to the update to target a single record by primary key `kd_buku` value.  Try using this version of your stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ubahbuku
(IN p_kd_buku VARCHAR(5), IN p_judul_buku VARCHAR(60), IN p_kd_karang VARCHAR(5), IN p_kd_terbit VARCHAR(5), p_jumlah INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE buku
    SET judul_buku = p_judul_buku, kd_karang = p_kd_karang, kd_terbit = p_kd_terbit, jumlah = p_jumlah
    WHERE kd_buku = p_kd_buku;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: there are no an error but the contents of my table haven't changed

Comment: Reload your page as I have updated my answer a few times.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert the value 24 for the primary key(kd_buku) through the procedure which is already inserted using this statement. This is the reason it is throwing a duplicate entry error.

```
INSERT INTO buku VALUES
('24','Pengantar Teknologi Informasi','12','3',41);
```

Comment: Looked at the update statement. From this we are trying to update the whole table, and kd_buku being the primary key column cannot have multiple rows with value as 24. So, it is pretty obvious   we will be getting the duplicate entry error here. This is the expected result after the above proc execution which is not possible.                       `('24','sosiologi','10','1',30),
 ('24','sosiologi','10','1',30),
 ('24','sosiologi','10','1',30),
 ('24','sosiologi','10','1',30),
 ('24','sosiologi','10','1',30)`

Comment: Yeah. Try to add a where clause according to your use case and have a close look on the kd_buku value being inserted making sure of no duplicacy.